# How do I normalize data before SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, projective-geometry, svd

Consider a satellite orbiting earth taking images. Since the problem can be approximated by the satellite moving with constant velocity and orientation relative to the fixed ground; the projection from world coordinates (X,Y,Z) to image coordinates (u,v) is a linear homogenous transform which in this case takes the form (1):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ 
wv \\
w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} & M_{24} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} & M_{34} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\ 
Y \\
Z \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The first equation can be rewritten as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
X & Y & Z & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} \\ 
M_{12} \\ 
M_{13} \\ 
M_{14} 
\end{bmatrix} = u
$$

Since there are 4 unknowns we need at least 4 points i to determine $M_{1i}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_1 & Y_1 & Z_1 & 1 \\
X_2 & Y_2 & Z_2 & 1 \\
X_3 & Y_3 & Z_3 & 1 \\
X_4 & Y_4 & Z_4 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} \\ 
M_{12} \\ 
M_{13} \\ 
M_{14} 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\ 
u_2 \\ 
u_3 \\ 
u_4 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

However what further requirements do we have on the points?
Let us denote the 4x4 matrix above by A.
For this to work A must be full rank? Otherwise the equation system is underdetermined?
And the rank of A is the dimension of the vector space spanned by the row vectors.

**Does this imply that 3 of the points must span a plane (not collinear) and the fourth point must lay outside this plane?**

I plan on solving this using SVD with more than 4 points. However I have one problem: the scale of the variables are quite different:
$$
0 <= X <= 1.0
$$

$$
-0.4 <= Y <= 0.4 
$$

$$
0 <= Z <= 0.05
$$

$$
-1 <= u <= 1
$$
$$
-1 <= v <= 1
$$

I understand this is not ideal for SVD?

**How can I "normalize" the data before SVD so that the range of the Z values are approximately the same as the other coordinates?**

(1): [Linear Pushbroom Cameras](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ehartley/Papers/linear-pushbroom/PAMI/pami-paper.pdf)